# finding a base and exponent given 2 related numbers

Tags: linear-algebra

Given that:

$x^y=a$

($10•x)^y=b$

$b>a$

where $a$ and $b$ are natural numbers. If I know the values of $a$ and $b$, how do I solve for $x$ and $y$? Thanks!

Comment: Your second equation is $(10\cdot x)^y=b$ or $10\cdot x^y=b$?

Comment: What you've written will only be true if b =10a.  In which case x may be anything and y is the log a base x.

Comment: (10x)^y=b  .  sorry poor formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the second equation is $(10 \cdot x)^y=b$ than , using logarithms, becomes:

$y\ln 10 +y\ln x=\ln b$

from $x^y=a$ we have $y \ln x=\ln a \iff \ln x= \frac{\ln a}{y}$ ( if $y\ne 0$), so we have the equation:

$$
y \ln 10 +\ln a=\ln b
$$

that you can solve for $y$ . Can you do from this?

Comment: This is perfect, thank you very much!